# Linq with embedded functions

Tags: c#, .net, linq, salesforce, linq-to-objects

Okay, so here's my question. I'm working with a saveresult from the Salesforce API, and I am learning LINQ. It may not be the best thing to use here, I don't know, but this is what I'm trying to do, just more eloquently.

BTW, here's the saveresult[] class shrunk down to definitions:

```
public partial class SaveResult {

    private Error[] errorsField;
    private string idField;
    private bool successField;

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("errors")]
    public Error[] errors

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]
    public string id

    public bool success 
}
```

And here's waht I'm trying to do. Check for errors, return them if there are any in any of the returned save results, or return null if no errors.

```
string errors = null;
        foreach (SaveResult s in saved)
        {
            if (s.success) continue;
            else
            {
                foreach (Error e in s.errors)
                {
                    errors += String.Format("Errors on object: {0}. Error Code is: {1}. Error Message: {2}",
                                            s.id,e.statusCode.ToString(),e.message);
                }
            }
        }
```

So far I have:

```
return saved
   .Select(i => i.errors
      .Select(j => new { j.statusCode, j.message })
      .Distinct()
      .ToList()
      ).ToString();
```

I'm pretty sure I will need an anonymous function in there to evaluate i for errors before I go on.

Anyway, that's it. Thanks for the help (or the links pointing me to help!)

Comment: Oh, and it doesn't mean if the return object is traversible (yet), because right now I'm just putting the errors into a logger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the query syntax:

```
return string.Join("",
    from s in saved
    where ! s.Success
    from e in s.Errors
    select string.Format(
        "Errors on object: {0}. Error Code is: {1}. Error Message: {2}",
        s.id, e.statusCode);
```

This is translated to a `SelectMany` behind the scenes.

Comment: @Legatou: I think you should remove this comment. It is quite arrogant and also funny, because your answer is the only one that hasn't been upvoted.

Comment: Or perhaps comment on where the others are lacking. Constructive criticism is always appreciated and is better than compliments in terms of helping to gain insight into the problem (though of course compliments and constructive criticism is best).

Comment: Not too familiar with query syntax, but I like the simplicity and easy readability of this answer. Thanks Thom

Answer (score 3):

I think you want this:

```
errors =
    string.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
        saved.Where(x => !x.success)
             .SelectMany(x => x.errors
                               .Select(y => string.Format("Errors on object: {0}. "
                                                          + "Error Code is: {1}. "
                                                          + "Error Message: {2}",     
                                                          x.id,
                                                          y.statusCode.ToString(), 
                                                          y.message)));
```

Answer (score 2):

Generally where there's an object graph to be traversed, I prefer query syntax. This:

```
from saveResult in saved
where !saveResult.success
from error in s.errors
select 
    string.Format("Errors on object: {0}. Error Code is: {1}. Error Message: {2}",
    s.id, e.statusCode.ToString(), e.message)
```

will give a sequence of strings. To do what you're doing at the moment, you could `Join` them together with `string.Empty` as the separator, but you probably want some non-empty separator for readability.

I would say it makes more sense to return `string.Empty` than `null` when there are no errors, but there's nothing stopping you making that check if you want. In all:

```
var errors = 
    from saveResult in saved
    where !saveResult.success
    from error in s.errors
    select 
        string.Format("Errors on object: {0}. Error Code is: {1}. Error Message: {2}",
        s.id, e.statusCode.ToString(), e.message);

var aggregateErrors = string.Join(string.Empty, errors);

return string.IsNullOrEmpty(aggregateErrors)
    ? null
    : aggregateErrors;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return string.Join(Environment.NewLine, saved
    .Where(save => !save.success)
    .SelectMany(save => save.errors
        .Select(err => Tuple.Create(save.id, err.statusCode, err.message)))
    .Select(i => string.Format("Errors on object: {0}. Error Code is: {1}. Error Message: {2}", 
        i.Item1, i.Item2, i.Item3)));
```

Comment: Why use a tuple and not an anonymous type?  The anonymous type would be both more concise and more readable.

Comment: It's not less concise, it is ordered (like its consumer, string.Format), and the Tuple is released within a few lines so discovery of purpose is high.

Comment: I'd personally go with an anonymous type too. It is slightly shorter (though that isn't relevant hugely important) and means that you will have sensibly named properties being passed to string.Format. It might not be that hard to check what each of `Item1`, `Item2` and `Item3` are but if they were `id`, `statusCode` and `message` it wouldn't even require checking.